# How to use ivshmem-plain in libvirt xml?

Tags: python

On ubuntu 18.04, I need to share 2M readonly memory of the host to guest, no interrupts need. So I chose `ivshmem-plain`:

```
<shmem name='my_shmem0'>
  <model type='ivshmem-plain'/>
  <size unit='M'>4</size>
</shmem>
```

The name `my_shmem0` here identifies the source of shared memory.
How do I prepare the host memory?
Is it a simple file in `/dev/shm`?
I need to write some text into the memory and shared with guest.

Answer (score 0):

On host, you can use:

```
int fd = shm_open("my_shmem0",  O_RDWR, 0644 );
```

On guest, you can map BAR2 (`/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:07\:01.0/resources2`) on the corresponnding PCI device to access the same memory location.

```
lspci -s 07:01.0 -vv
```

> 07:01.0 RAM memory: Red Hat, Inc. Inter-VM shared memory (rev 01)
>   ...
>           Region 0: Memory at fda00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
>           Region 2: Memory at fc400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4M]